# Adding on-change to element in function that adds a row to a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript

Trying to add onchange that calls to another function to an element that is being added in a row on a table that is being added to a table on the page I have all parts of the function working except the on change  here is the code I have right now

```
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
        var element4 = document.createElement("select");
        element4.type = "select";
        element4.name = "R1Q1[]";
        element4.classList.add("white");
        element4.setAttribute("onChange", "changeColor('+element4.name+');");
        var option1 = document.createElement("option");
    option1.type = "option";
    option1.value = "5";
        option1.classList.add("blue");
    option1.innerHTML = "5";
    element4.appendChild(option1);
        var option2 = document.createElement("option");
    option2.type = "option";
    option2.value = "3";
        option2.classList.add("blue");
    option2.innerHTML = "3";
    element4.appendChild(option2);
        var option3 = document.createElement("option");
    option3.type = "option";
    option3.value = "1";
        option3.classList.add("blue");
    option3.innerHTML = "1";
    element4.appendChild(option3);
        var option4 = document.createElement("option");
    option4.type = "option";
    option4.value = "0";
        option4.classList.add("white");
        option4.setAttribute('selected', true);
    option4.innerHTML = "0";
    element4.appendChild(option4);
        var option5 = document.createElement("option");
    option5.type = "option";
    option5.value = "-1";
        option5.classList.add("red");
    option5.innerHTML = "-1";
    element4.appendChild(option5);
        var option6 = document.createElement("option");
    option6.type = "option";
    option6.value = "-3";
        option6.classList.add("red");
    option6.innerHTML = "-3";
    element4.appendChild(option6);
        var option7 = document.createElement("option");
    option7.type = "option";
    option7.value = "-5";
        option7.classList.add("red");
    option7.innerHTML = "-5";
    element4.appendChild(option7);
        cell4.appendChild(element4);
```

Comment: See the working solution below. Would you mind [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) i have solved your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use `onchange` function instead of using `setAttribute`. You can pass arguments to your `changeColor()` function.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
var element4 = document.createElement("select");
element4.type = "select";
element4.name = "R1Q1[]";
element4.classList.add("white");
element4.onchange = function() {
  changeColor(element4.name); //element4.name
};

var option1 = document.createElement("option");
option1.type = "option";
option1.value = "5";
option1.classList.add("blue");
option1.innerHTML = "5";
element4.appendChild(option1);
var option2 = document.createElement("option");
option2.type = "option";
option2.value = "3";
option2.classList.add("blue");
option2.innerHTML = "3";
element4.appendChild(option2);
var option3 = document.createElement("option");
option3.type = "option";
option3.value = "1";
option3.classList.add("blue");
option3.innerHTML = "1";
element4.appendChild(option3);
var option4 = document.createElement("option");
option4.type = "option";
option4.value = "0";
option4.classList.add("white");
option4.setAttribute('selected', true);
option4.innerHTML = "0";
element4.appendChild(option4);
var option5 = document.createElement("option");
option5.type = "option";
option5.value = "-1";
option5.classList.add("red");
option5.innerHTML = "-1";
element4.appendChild(option5);
var option6 = document.createElement("option");
option6.type = "option";
option6.value = "-3";
option6.classList.add("red");
option6.innerHTML = "-3";
element4.appendChild(option6);
var option7 = document.createElement("option");
option7.type = "option";
option7.value = "-5";
option7.classList.add("red");
option7.innerHTML = "-5";
element4.appendChild(option7);
document.body.appendChild(element4)

//Change color function
function changeColor(name) {
  console.log(name)
}
```